# How can I avoid repopulating my tf.data shuffle buffer on each tf.keras epoch when using tf.distribute?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm doing a Keras model with (on `tf-nightly-gpu==1.13.0.dev20190116`):

```
with tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy().scope():
    model = tf.keras.Model(...)
```

and a dataset with:

```
dataset = (tf.data.Dataset
    .list_files(...)
    .map(load_example)
    .cache()
    .shuffle(100)
    .repeat())
```

and then training with

```
model.fit(dataset, epochs=10, steps_per_epoch=1000)
```

which works great as it automatically splits my minibatch up on my single-machine multi-GPU setup. Very cool!

However, my shuffle buffer is repopulated on each epoch. Is there a way that I can keep the shuffle buffer over epochs? I tried calling `model.fit` with iterators and tensors directly but tf.distribute doesn't support that (yet?) and raises an exception instead.

**TL;DR: How do I make sure my tf.data shuffle buffer is maintained across epochs?**

Comment: [shuffle](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#shuffle) has a reshuffle_each_iteration argument that you can set to False. Would that be helpful?

Comment: Oh yes! Of course! Completely overlooked that argument. Thanks! Provide an answer and I'll mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[shuffle](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#shuffle) has an argument reshuffle_each_iteration, that you can set to False so that the shuffling happens in the 1st epoch only and the state is maintained in future epochs.